# Can I make a HTML5 date input look the same in both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, mozilla

My code is very simple:

```
<input type="date">
```

While I run it in Firefox and Chrome I get two different designs:

#### Firefox:

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

#### Chrome:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

Not only design is different, but the functionality also little bit different. In Mozilla when I click inside the date box it will show date, but in Chrome if we want date box we should click on drop down arrow symbol.

Is there any way to change the functionality and design so that it works and looks the same in both browsers?

Comment: Search the web for datepicker

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply but Without Datepicker is there any way..Bcoz our task is not using datepicker. Sorry i forgot to mentioned this. @mplungjan

Comment: That is just the way it is. If you do not like it and are not allowed to use a datepicker, you will have to roll your own

Comment: What do you mean with "design was changed"? Was there a time where both development teams agreed to implement the same UI design?

Answer (score 5):

It is different from one browser to another. However end result will be added values to the input field.

> The **control's UI varies in general from browser to browser**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

**Customized DatePicker**

If you need this field should act same as every browser, please use a custom Javascript generated date picker.

- https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
- [18+ Best Free Date Pickers In Pure JavaScript And CSS - CSS Script](https://www.cssscript.com/tag/date-picker/)
- https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/